# Stream Operation of Two dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to find the best average score from below two dimensional array:

```
String[][] scores = { { "Amit", "70" }, { "Arthit", "60" }, { "Peter", "60" }, { "Arthit", "100" } };
```

**The output is:** 80 (Arthit's score (60+100)/2)

Till now I solved this problem with below approach, however I am looking for elegant solution with stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] scores = { { "Amit", "70" }, { "Arthit", "60" }, { "Peter", "60" }, { "Arthit", "100" } };

        int highestAvg = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Function<String[], Integer> function = new Function<String[], Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(String[] t) {
                int sum = 0, count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                    if (t[0].equals(scores[i][0])) {
                        count++;
                        sum += Integer.parseInt(scores[i][1]);
                    }
                }
                int avg = sum / count;
                return highestAvg < avg ? avg : highestAvg;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(scores).map(function).max((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2)).get());
    }
```

Would you please suggest, what's the better approach to handle two dimensional array using stream?

Note: **I am not looking the exact solution, just looking your valuable suggestion.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make more use of built-in stream features, including [averaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and [grouping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collectors:

```
Stream.of(scores)
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], 
                Collectors.averagingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]))))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .ifPresent(bestScore -> {
                String message = String.format("Best score is %s, by %s", bestScore.getValue(), bestScore.getKey());
                System.out.println(message);
        });
```

Which prints `Best score is 80.0, by Arthit`

Answer (score 2):

I know an answer has been submitted and accepted already, but just sharing what I found while trying to answer your question.

```
Map<String, Double> collect = Arrays.stream(scores)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], 
             Collectors.averagingDouble(arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[1]))));
```

Here the `key` is the name and the `value` is the average of his scores. Now you can iterate over this map to find the largest value and hence the index of the largest key.

EDIT :

To find the max value from the map use :

```
Entry<String, Double> entry = collect.entrySet().stream()
         .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.doubleValue())))
         .get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all you want as a result is the best average score, then you can do as follows:

```
Collection<Double> values = Arrays.stream(scores)
                .collect(groupingBy(a -> a[0], averagingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]))))
                .values();

System.out.println(Collections.max(values));
```

This streams over the `scores` multidimensional array and uses the `groupingBy` collector to accumulate the elements into groups by their names and then uses the `averagingInt` as a downstream collector to get the averages and then finally use `Collections.max(values)` to get the best average score.

Another approach:

```
double bestAverage = 
       Arrays.stream(scores)
             .collect(groupingBy(a -> a[0], averagingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]))))
             .values()
             .stream()
             .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
             .max().getAsDouble();

System.out.println(bestAverage);
```

Note, that both approaches above will result in an exception if the source is empty, so if you want to handle that then you can use `isPresent` or some of the other [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) methods as such of `orElse` et al.

```
Arrays.stream(scores)
      .collect(groupingBy(a -> a[0], averagingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]))))
      .values()
      .stream()
      .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
      .max().ifPresent(v -> ...);
```

imports:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```